# scrollTop() with slideDown() Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide a div if user scrolls down & show it if user scrolls up.

Here's my code,

```
<div class="baseNav">
    # some data
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var senseSpeed = 2,
        prevScroll = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        var o = $(this).scrollTop();
        var nav = $(".baseNav");
        o - senseSpeed > prevScroll ? nav.filter(":not(:animated)").slideUp() : o + senseSpeed < prevScroll ? nav.filter(":not(:animated)").slideDown() : $(window).scrollTop() && nav.filter(":not(:animated)").slideDown(), prevScroll = o
    })
});
```

When user `smoothly` scrolls down it hides the div, also when user `smoothly` scrolls up it shows it.

Problem is, in case user scrolls down and then very suddenly scrolls up it doesn't show the div. So, I think it would be a better idea to `show the div` (in any case) when user (or cursor) is within 100px range from the top.

How can we do that?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show and hide the div using the inbuilt fadeout and fadedin option of javascript and jQuery.

Please try the below one.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
     {
        $('.fade').fadeOut();
     }
    else
     {
      $('.fade').fadeIn();
     }
 });
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;    
}
.fade {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #d15757;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
The below div will get faded out on scrolling. 
    <div class="fade">
        Scroll down i will become invisible
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

by default make the element visible via css

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop > 100){
            $('.elem').hide();
        }
        else{
            $('.elem').show();
        }
    });
```